# Common "Debug" function within class library

Tags: c#

I am using several class libraries within a project, and one of them is a typical "project.common.dll" library containing some common helper functions. One of these functions is a debug function that creates debug output. 
Now I would like to enable/disable debug output by using a user-level property (application settings). How can I reference variables defined in main application's program.cs within this class library ?

Update : Thanks all. I will probably create a static method in my base application that performs the check (to debug or not) and then calls the Debug function in the common library.

Comment: Why not use the if debug compile flag?

Comment: You cannot reference variables from your main program in your class library, you have to put these variables in a separate library

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

What you will need to do is have the properties in the class library itself and when you create the instance of it in your main application pass the user setting in:

```
var debug = new DebugInstance { Output = this.Output };
```

or set the parameters if it's a static class:

```
StaticDebug.Output = this.Output;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ConditionalAtrribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx):

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void WriteDebugInfo()
{
    Trace.WriteLine("what ever...")
}
```

This way when you build in Debug mode, the method is invoked; in Release mode not.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters on the constructor of the Debug class (or a static constructor if the class is static).